# When I extract an application that I have downloaded, where should I be extracting them to?

Tags: installation, command-line, archive

What do I type into the terminal to tell it where to go? I don't really understand how to move files using the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

> The question is **where** to extract application files, so I'd
>   recommend to extract it to a *temporary folder* inside `/home`
>   directory and then copy it into a permanent location in the file
>   system.

## **For `deb` files**

**Method 1: using `dpkg`**

**deb** is the extension of the Debian software package format and the most often used name for such binary packages.

**dpkg** is the package manager for Debian. So using dpkg command you can *list* and *extract* deb packages.

- Use `dpkg -c` to list the contents of a deb package:

  ```
  $ dpkg -c <file-name>.deb
  ```
- Use `dpkg -x` to extract the files from a deb package:

  ```
  $ dpkg -x <file-name>.deb </path/to/temp-dir>
  ```

**Method 2: using `ar`**

**Debian packages** are standard Unix [ar archives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) that include two **tar** archives optionally compressed with gzip (zlib), Bzip2, lzma, or xz (lzma2): one archive holds the **control information** and another contains the **program data**.

Therefore `.deb` files always contains three files — `debian-binary`, `control.tar.gz`, and `data.tar.gz`.

Use `ar` and `tar` command to extract and view the files from the deb package.

- To extract the contents of `.deb` archive to your `/home` directory:

  ```
  $ ar -vx <file-name>.deb
  x - debian-binary
  x - control.tar.gz
  x - data.tar.gz
  ```
- To extract the contents of `data.tar.gz` file:

  ```
  $ tar -xvzf data.tar.gz </path/to/temp-dir>
  ```
- To extract the files into the root directory tree, which should place everything where it should go, you can:

  ```
  $ tar -xvzf data.tar.gz /
  ```

**Note:**

`deb` files should be installed with **dpkg**, so to install the package, do:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file-name>.deb
```

If the `deb` file(s) are in another directory inside your `/home` directory, you can install it by:

```
cd <directory>
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

---

## **For Tar files**

**TAR**(tape archive) is a file format (in the form of a type of archive bitstream) for archiving files.

- To extract a tar file:

  ```
  tar -xvf file.tar
  ```
- To extract a .tar.gz (gzip) file, (note -z option):

  ```
  tar -xzvf file.tar.gz
  ```
- To extract .tar.bz2 (bzip2) file, (note -j option):

  ```
  tar -xjvf file.tar.bz2
  ```

By default files will be extracted into the current directory. To change the directory use `-C` option.

For example, to extract to `/home/data`:

```
tar -zxvf data.tar.gz -C /home/data
```

- To view a detailed table of contents (list all files) for this archive:

  ```
  tar -tzvf data.tar.gz
  ```

---

## **Using a GUI tool: Archive Manager**

You can use the Archive Manager GUI application to create, view, modify, or extract an archive.

1. Press the Super key to Open the Dash and type Archive Manager. This will launch the Archive Manager window.

   [image]
2. Click on **Open** and **browse** for the tar or deb file.
3. Click on **Extract** and **select** the directory to where you want to extract the file.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the application is. If it's a `.deb` file, you can say:

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

If it's a `.tar.gz` file, you can say:

```
tar zvxf filename.tar.gz
cd directory-name
make
make install
# (or ./install or similar)
```

Comment: Thanks, its a tar.gz file. now how do i extract using the terminal? right now the file is in my downloads folder

Answer (score 0):

Not to minimize other excellent answers, I wanted to provide a very simple answer.

If the file ends with `.tar.gz` (or `.tgz`), move the file to the directory to which you want to extract it and `cd` to that directory. Then:

```
tar xzvf filename.tar.gz
```

If the filename ends with `.tar.bz2` or `.tbz`, then change the `z` in the above command to a `j`.

## Which directory?

*Any directory you like.* I normally use `/tmp` because everything there is automatically deleted on reboot. If the program is designed to be run directly after extracting it without running an installer, then the traditional location would be `~/bin`.